# Multidimensionnal ARRAY - 3 and 4 levels

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have this 3 and 4 multidimensionnal array ($response) which I need to "extract" some values.

```
Array ( 
[status] => 200 
[response] => Array ( 
    [api_id] => 38229dd9-8c52-11e5-80f6-22000afd0039 
    [meta] => Array ( 
        [limit] => 20 
        [next] => /v1/Account/xxx/Call/?limit=20&offset=20 
        [offset] => 0 
        [previous] => 
        [total_count] => 57 ) 
    [objects] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [answer_time] => 2015-11-13 18:36:19+01:00 
            [bill_duration] => 10 
            [billed_duration] => 60 
            [call_direction] => inbound 
            [call_duration] => 10 
            [call_uuid] => dcd94e59-8775-4c81-a4b1-cd5d41d630c6 
            [end_time] => 2015-11-13 18:36:29+01:00 
            [from_number] => 3300000000 
            [initiation_time] => 2015-11-13 18:36:18+01:00 
            [parent_call_uuid] => 
            [resource_uri] => /v1/Account/xxx/Call/dcd94e59-8775-4c81-a4b1-cd5d41d630c6/ 
            [to_number] => 3300000000 
            [total_amount] => 0.00500 
            [total_rate] => 0.00500 ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [answer_time] => 2015-11-13 15:52:01+01:00 [
            bill_duration] => 48 
            [billed_duration] => 60 
            [call_direction] => inbound 
            [call_duration] => 48 
            [call_uuid] => b2d3de5d-a047-4409-9f7a-825373c38f0a 
            [end_time] => 2015-11-13 15:52:48+01:00 
            [from_number] => 3300000000 
            [initiation_time] => 2015-11-13 15:52:00+01:00 
            [parent_call_uuid] => 
            [resource_uri] => /v1/Account/xxx/Call/b2d3de5d-a047-4409-9f7a-825373c38f0a/ 
            [to_number] => 3300000000 
            [total_amount] => 0.00500 
            [total_rate] => 0.00500 ) 
        ...
```

In the [meta] array, I need the [total_count] value and for the [object] array, I'd like to get all the values to disaply them in a row (each object is a new row).

I have tried foreach within foreach or access datas with $response[0][0][0] but nothing do.

If someone could lead me to the solution...

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: It's `foreach($response->objects as $key => $object)` then you can use e.g.  `$object->answer_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the meta array through `$response['response']['meta']`. As you can see from your array, both `response` and meta are keys, and so is `total_count`. Hence, accessing total count is done by `$response['response']['meta']['total_count']`.

To then loop through all your objects, simply do

```
foreach ($response['response']['objects'] as $object) {
    print_r($object);
}
```

You can also access every attribute of the object individually by using the array keys:

```
foreach ($response['response']['objects'] as $object) {
    echo $object['answer_time'];
    echo $object['bill_duration'];
    echo $object['billed_duration'];
    echo $object['call_direction'];
    echo $object['call_duration'];
    echo $object['call_uuid'];
    echo $object['end_time'];
    echo $object['from_number'];
    echo $object['initiation_time'];
    echo $object['parent_call_uuid'];
    echo $object['resource_uri'];
    echo $object['to_number'];
    echo $object['total_amount'];
    echo $object['total_rate'];
}
```

Comment: And how can I only get the values of $object ?

Comment: You can access it through the array keys, so `$object['billed_duration']` for example. Gonna update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "count" function with "COUNT_RECURSIVE" flag. It counts all the items inside the 'mixed' var. It counts parent element too.

```
count($array['objects'],COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

example

```
$cibo = array(
        'frutta' => array('arancia', 'banana', 'mela'),
        'verdura' => array('carota', 'zucchina', 'piselli')
);

echo count($cibo,COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, i was to lazy! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, to verify, if `$array` is the name of your array:

```
$response = $array["response"];
```

---

> In the [meta] array, I need the [total_count] value

```
echo $response["meta"]["total_count"];
```

---

> and for the [object] array, I'd like to get all the values to disaply them in a row (each object is a new row).

Use a `foreach()` function for all the objects:

```
foreach($response["objects"] as $object){
    print_r($object);
}
```

Comment: First part works : echo $array["response"]["meta"]["total_count"];